# Single Sign On With ACS through Multiple Applications

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on, acs

Simple Single Sign-On question

I Have two MVC4 applications:

```
  **1**- http://localhost/BikeShop    

   ACS Relying Party:

 - Name: **BikeShop**
 - Return Url: **http://localhost/BikeShop**
 - Token Format: **SAML 2.0**


**2**- http://localhost/BikePartsShop

   ACS Relying Party:

 - Name: **BikePartsShop**
 - Return Url: **http://localhost/BikePartsShop**
 - Token Format: **SAML 2.0**
```

---

**The Scenario I have**

I access **BikeShop** and the ACS Login Page is presented and I choose my Identity.

I now can do stuff on **BikeShop**.

Then I access **BikePartsShop** and the ACS Login Page is presented and I can choose my Identity.

---

**The Scenario I must have**

I access **BikeShop** and the ACS Login Page is presented and I choose my Identity.

I now can do stuff on **BikeShop**.

Then I access **BikePartsShop** and the ACS authorizes the same Identity 
used in the **BikeShop** without further user intervention.

---

Has anyone implemented this scenario?

Best Regards, and thank you!

Comment: Should BikeShop and BikePartsShop be one RP rather than two? One RP can support multiple reply addresses, and this would allow the same token to be used at both.

Comment: How can it be achieved with ACS.

ACS Relay Parties can only have one Reply Address configure (Return Url)

Comment: That's not true, ACS supports configuring as many reply addresses as you want. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ACS management service to configure multiple reply addresses for the same relying party. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135147.aspx) for details on how to add an RP. From the linked code sample, register more addresses as follows:

```
RelyingParty relyingParty = new RelyingParty()
{
     Name = "BikeShop",
     AsymmetricTokenEncryptionRequired = false,
     TokenType = "SAML_2_0",
     TokenLifetime = 3600
};

svc.AddToRelyingParties(relyingParty);

RelyingPartyAddress realm = new RelyingPartyAddress()
{
    Address = "http://localhost/",
    EndpointType = "Realm"
};

RelyingPartyAddress replyAddress1 = new RelyingPartyAddress()
{
    Address = "http://localhost/BikeShop",
    EndpointType = "Reply"
};

RelyingPartyAddress replyAddress2 = new RelyingPartyAddress()
{
    Address = "http://localhost/BikePartsShop",
    EndpointType = "Reply"
};

svc.AddRelatedObject(relyingParty, "RelyingPartyAddresses", realmAddress);
svc.AddRelatedObject(relyingParty, "RelyingPartyAddresses", replyAddress1);
svc.AddRelatedObject(relyingParty, "RelyingPartyAddresses", replyAddress2);

svc.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);
```

Comment: I will try that solution. Thank you!

Comment: After implementing all the code and being able to successfuly deploy and run it, the ACS Relying Party was created, the Identity Providers added, and reply addresses configured. All the rules execute correctly for both apps. The Claims are being correctly constructed. But I still cannot change between sites without showing the "Log-On" screen from ACS, where you choose the Identity Provider you want to use.

Comment: Do you have them both configured under the same WSFederationAuthenticationModule and SessionAuthenticationModule in web.config? It sounds like one site isn't seeing the other site's cookies.

Comment: Its the same WSFederationAuthenticationModule and SessionAuthenticationModule, with the same Realm, the same Relying Party in the ACS and the same Trusts, Audience Uris, etc. I've tryed even use the same cookie name in the cookieHandler element, but only to screw the fist cookie on the second site authentication.

Comment: I assume these can't just be put under the same ASP.NET website? If not, this sounds like a WIF issue that I don't know the answer to and may be worth asking as a separate question tagged under "WIF". Your problem is that you have two sites with the same realm and you want them to be able to share cookies; I'm not sure if this is possible or not. One alternate solution is to add an RP-STS in between ACS and your RPs that saves the token.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code to help you forward to a specific identity provider, if you can figure out how to remember which identity provider they last used.  The last login should be stored so that you will automatically 302 back to your app.

```
public IdentityProvider GetIdentityProvider(string identityProviderName, string realm , string audienceUri )
        {
            // acs config parameters
            string acsNamespace = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Namespace"];
            realm = realm ?? Uri.EscapeDataString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Realm"]);
            audienceUri = audienceUri ?? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AudienceUri"];

            string returnPath = Uri.EscapeDataString("/home/index");
            var newReplyTo =
                Uri.EscapeDataString(audienceUri.Replace(new Uri(audienceUri).Authority,
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority));
            // retrieve current identity providers
            string idpDiscoveryUrl = string.Format("{0}v2/metadata/IdentityProviders.js?protocol=wsfederation&realm={1}&reply_to={2}&context=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d{3}&request_id=&version=1.0", acsNamespace, realm, newReplyTo, returnPath);
            string response = null;
            using (var client = new WebClient()) {
            response = client.DownloadString(idpDiscoveryUrl);    
            }

            List<IdentityProvider> identityProviders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IdentityProvider>>(response);
            // lookup provider for tenant
            var identityProvider = identityProviders.Where(i => i.Name == identityProviderName).FirstOrDefault() ?? new IdentityProvider();

            return identityProvider;
        }
```